# Floating point exception (core dumped) in linux 64bit nasm assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm

I want to write a simple program that takes two integer numbers, divides them, converts the result into string and prints it to a screen.

Here's the part of code I got. It converts floating point number to an integer portion. There's an error there somewhere. It causes the floating point exception. [Here I've tried to explain myself what actually happens within my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ejbL.jpg)

```
_getTempIntegerPortion:
        mov r8, temp
        mov rcx, 10
        xor rdx, rdx

; Input - rax as integer, r8 as pointer to temp, rcx is 10
_assignTempIntegerPortion:
        div rcx 
        cmp rax, 0
        mov rax, rdx
        add rdx, 48
        mov [r8], dl
        inc r8
        jne _assignTempIntegerPortion
        ret
```

Comment: You need to zero RDX *inside* the loop, before every `div`.  Look at registers with a debugger when you fault: you'll have RDX = '0' + something, so it'll be greater than 10.  Also, `inc r8` / `jne` will loop until the pointer wraps around, so it'll segfault way before that.

Comment: Thanks for answer and I've tried, but it didn't help.

Comment: `div rcx` with RDX=0 can't fault (with non-zero RCX).  If you're still getting SIGFPE, you have another `div` somewhere else in your program that's also faulting.  Use a debugger to find out where.  See the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for asm debugging tips with GDB.  (And/or see [How do I print an integer in Assembly Level Programming without printf from the c library? (itoa, integer to decimal ASCII string)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46301894) for a working loop.)

Comment: Just noticed you are apparently trying to exit after division produces a `0`.  You need `cmp rax, 0` to be the last thing that sets FLAGS before `jne`, so it needs to come after the `inc`.  Also, `mov rax, rdx` is wrong; you want `x /= 10` across loop iterations, not `x %= 10`